# Laravel file_put_contents(..../session/....) failed to open stream

Tags: laravel-5.7, php-7.3

I started to upload my project to a hosting server. But I got this error when I try to access a subdomain:

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\njt_private_project\thermo\storage\framework/sessions/JyNXpbnsmCU6vLK2OsPVRHPaQmvMQK5YIem2QXUt): failed to open stream
>   .

As I understand laravel still use my local cache even in the server. How can I fix this issue manually?

Note: I don't have access to the terminal in my serve so i can't clear or config or run in artisan command.

Comment: have you try to change permission on the folder? something like `sudo chmod -R 777 *` on the root directory of the project (or right click, change permission and set everything to rean and write). Also remember to go inside bootstrap/cache and delete all the file inside it, and also inside storage/logs, when moving the project in another server

Comment: also, if you can't access the terminal, just create a route temporarily and inside the function put `Artisan::call('config:clear');` and it will run it (if it has the right privileges)